# Context dependable dynamic context menus in VS Code TreeView?

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

I am building VS Code extension to support Git Flow. I have a dedicated View Container with  TreeView with tree of branches, including features, releases, hotfixes, ...

[image]

What I want to do is a right click menu on a viewItem bit with a different list of elements. For instance when I right click on feature I want:

Checkout feature
Rebase feature
Pull feature
Finish feature

Yet Checkout feature only if I right click on features that are not current branch.

I know about `when` in `configuration.menus` but I cannot access individual `viewItem` property there or can I?

Right now, the only way I see is to create a separate view in my view container for each prefix. One for feature, one for releases one for hotfixes. But that is not the way I would like it to be. In my opinion one tree with all branches is easier to use.

Does anyone know how to achieve custom context menus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vscode.TreevItem` has a property `contextValue`, assign this a string and use this in the `when` clause of the menu item

```
"when": "view == myGitFlow && viewItem == current"

"when": "view == myGitFlow && viewItem != current"
```

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you. I read documentation again to find where I missed this, and I still could not find this, or at least it was not clear to me.