# How to build VS Code TreeView with custom JSON?

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to build a TreeView based on a JSON file / REST Call and have an icon for each type of my objects. I have only three types of objects: Server, Host and Group. For each type I'd like to have a custom icon and configuration.menu similar to what I found here [dynamic context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70837298/context-dependable-dynamic-context-menus-in-vs-code-treeview).

I'm new to VS Code extensions building. I've tried to modify the `constructor(){this.data ...}`  to get the json file and tinkered with the class `class TreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem` , however I'm not yet fully grasping the behavior I need of the class and code I need to change.

My current code:

```
import * as vscode from 'vscode';
import * as json from 'jsonc-parser';
import * as path from 'path';


export class CtmInfraProvider implements vscode.TreeDataProvider<TreeItem> {
  onDidChangeTreeData?: vscode.Event<TreeItem | null | undefined> | undefined;

  data: TreeItem[];

  constructor() {
    this.data = [new TreeItem('Agents', [
      new TreeItem(
        'datacenter', [new TreeItem('xyz.domain.name'), new TreeItem('xyz.domain.name'), new TreeItem('xyz.domain.name')])
    ]),
    new TreeItem('Groups', [
      new TreeItem(
        'abcd', [new TreeItem('xyz.domain.name'), new TreeItem('abc.domain.name'), new TreeItem('123.domain.name')]),
      new TreeItem(
        'wxyz', [new TreeItem('efg.domain.name'), new TreeItem('456.domain.name')])
    ])

    ];
  }

  getTreeItem(element: TreeItem): vscode.TreeItem | Thenable<vscode.TreeItem> {
    return element;
  }

  getChildren(element?: TreeItem | undefined): vscode.ProviderResult<TreeItem[]> {
    if (element === undefined) {
      return this.data;
    }
    return element.children;
  }

}

class TreeItem extends vscode.TreeItem {

  constructor(
    public readonly label: string,
    public children?: TreeItem[],
    public readonly command?: vscode.Command,
    public iconPath?: { light: string, dark: string }
  ) {
    super(
      label,
      children === undefined ? vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None :
        vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.Expanded);
    this.children = children;
    // this.type = type;
    this.tooltip = `Agent Details:\n - Datacenter: demo\n - OS: Linux \n - Version: 20.22.04.00\n - Status: Available`;
    // this.description = 'Hello Desc';
  }

  setConfiguredIcon(): void {
    let newLightIcon: any;
    let newDarkIcon: any;

    newLightIcon = path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'resources', 'light', 'dna.svg');
    newDarkIcon = path.join(__filename, '..', '..', 'resources', 'dark', 'dna.svg');

    if (this.iconPath === undefined) {
      this.iconPath = {
        light: newLightIcon,
        dark: newDarkIcon
      };
    }
    else {
      this.iconPath = {
        light: newLightIcon,
        dark: newDarkIcon
      };
    }
  }

}
```

The desired result, missing icon and menu:
[TreeView based on hard-coded json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLd2T.png)

Here is a copy of the json file I'm looking at. If there is a better format, the json file can be adjusted anytime.

```
{
    "inventory": {
        "servers": [
            {
                "server": "abcd",
                "host": "abcd.domain.name",
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "nodeid": "xyz.domain.name",
                        "operating_system": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016  (Build 14393)",
                        "status": "Available",
                        "version": "20.22.04.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "nodeid": "xyz.domain.name",
                        "operating_system": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016  (Build 14393)",
                        "status": "Available",
                        "version": "20.22.04.00"
                    },
                    {
                        "nodeid": "xyz.domain.name",
                        "operating_system": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016  (Build 14393)",
                        "status": "Available",
                        "version": "20.22.04.00"
                    }
                ],
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "groupid": "abcd",
                        "nodes": "xyz.domain.name,abc.domain.name,123.domain.name"
                    },
                    {
                        "groupid": "wxyz",
                        "nodes": "efg.domain.name,456.domain.name"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "server": "1234",
                "host": "1234.domain.name",
                "nodes": null
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: Do you actually call `setConfiguredIcon()` anywhere?  You can take that function code out of the function, I don't really see a need to have it within a function within the `TreeItem` class.

Comment: Mark, I'm not calling ```setConfiguredIcon()``` yet. This will come into play when I'm able to identify the type of object: Server, Node or Group.

Comment: What isn't working then?  I thought from your question that you were having icon problems.

Comment: My challenge is to get the tree populated by an json file. Currently I have it "hard-coded" in the ```constructor()```. Thank you for taking a look at this. I'm researching in addition to this post on how to get the data in.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get the vscode.treeview populated with my json data.

[custom treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzeLK.png) the source code will be open sourced and hosted on git soon. The code is quite large to accommodate for all the different objects. Now I have to figured out how to update the treeview when the refresh button is clicked and how to invoke a custom command on a treeview item. I will create new questions for this to better track it.

Regards.